# About the existence of two maximal normal subgroups of diff order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H \text{ &}  K$ are two distinct normal subgroups such that both the quotient groups $G/H$ and $G/K$ are simple. Can such subgroups exist with the property that $o(H)$ is not equal to $o(K)$. I mean for $o(H)=o(K)$ the matter is easy but for the other case in which they are not equal it is relatively hard

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can. If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two (finite) simple groups of different orders, then $G = G_1\times G_2$ has this property, with $H = \{(g, e_{G_2}) \mid g\in G_1\}$ and $K = \{( e_{G_1}, g) \mid g\in G_2\}$. For a specific example, you have $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, with $H = (3)$ and $K = (2)$.